# How to get the list of all YouTube Channel ids?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I was wondering whether there is a way to get all the you tube channels ids?
Looking at the Google Data API, I do not see a way of doing this.

Of course, the data coming back will have to be paginated!

Thanks,
Behzad

Comment: Do you mean the id of every single channel? Or of all the channels owned by a particular user?

Comment: @jlmcdonald: The first one, the id of every single channel regardless of the user!

Comment: That's going to be tricky. The full data is not exposed; to search for channels it's mandatory to pass in a filter parameter (either by Id, sername, category, etc.).

Comment: @jlmcdonald: Actually, I was able to do it through youtube.search.list. Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: @BehzadPirvali Can you elaborate please?  I'm interested in doing the same thing and youtube.search.list seems to limit the number of search results to around 500 even if the totalResults count is much higher.

Comment: @ProGirlXOXO Honestly, it is going back two years and I do not remember the details, but I do remember getting a lot more than 500 channel ids. I barely remember that I was using a database/tool (forget  the name of it, though) of different video categories. I have used these categories as filter to narrow down the youtube.search.list results, but then walked through the whole filter-tree and de-duped duplicate channel-ids. I hope this helps